# Subquery returned more than 1 value. How to add more values to the column?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a query (sql server and oracle) that each column is made by a different query. So the first column called "presentes" is:

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.SESSION = 92
```

The second column called "justificados" is:

```
SELECT TABLE2.NAME FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.SESSION = 92 AND TABLE2.DATE > '[somedateGoesHere]'
```

The Third column called "ausentes" is:

```
SELECT TABLE3.NAME FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.SESSION = 92
```

So I'm trying to put all of this information in a single query, like:

```
SELECT (SELECT TABLE1.NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.SESSION = 92) AS presentes,
(SELECT TABLE2.NAME FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.SESSION = 92 AND TABLE2.DATE > '[somedateGoesHere]') as justificados,
(SELECT TABLE3.NAME FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.SESSION = 92) as ausentes
```

The idea is return something like this:

[image: query expected]

But I'm receiving this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I know that is because the third column has more than 1 value. But how can I add "null" values to the other columns to fix it?

Comment: Does it make sense? Your columns are unrelated sets of data. Why would you want them in a single table?

Comment: Because I'm using Jasper report and I need to set this information in only 1 dataset

Comment: Why do you want 3 columns? Is it not enough with an union all tagging each query to know where the data come from? Then you could pivot if you want but not sure why do you need that weird unrelated data in columns

Comment: Can you show me one example? As I said, this will be turns into a report from Jasper, but Jasper has some limitations, so I need to put this unrelated queries toghether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with `union all` & do conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when tb = 'table1' then name end) as presentes,
       max(case when tb = 'table2' then name end) as justificados,
       max(case when tb = 'table3' then name end) as ausentes
from (select 'table1' as tb, name, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as seq
      from table1 
      where SESSION = 92 
      union all
      select 'table2', name, row_number() over (order by (select 1))  
      from table2
      where SESSION = 92 AND DATE > '[somedateGoesHere]' 
      union all
      select 'table3', name, row_number() over (order by (select 1))  
      from table3
      where SESSION = 92
     ) t
group by seq;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from TABLE3 and do a LEFT JOIN against both of the other two

```
SELECT t1.NAME as presentes, t2.name AS justificados, t3.NAME as ausentes
FROM TABLE3 t3
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t3.session = t1.session
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t3.session = t2.session
WHERE t3.SESSION = 92 
  AND t2.DATE = '[someDate]'
```

alternatively the last where condition can be used directly in the JOIN

```
SELECT t1.NAME as presentes, t2.name AS justificados, t3.NAME as ausentes
FROM TABLE3 t3
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t3.session = t1.session
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t3.session = t2.session AND t2.DATE = '[someDate]'
WHERE t3.SESSION = 92
```

Comment: My WHERE clauses are different from each subquery

Comment: You mean session is not the same value for all? And why the down vote?

Comment: The session is the same value, but the WHERE clauses is differents. Some has date comparission as you can see on my main question

Comment: @aseolin Yes and I have that in my where clause too! Look at the last row.

Answer (score 0):

you could use union all

```
SELECT TABLE1.NAME as presentes,
'' as justificados,'' as ausentes FROM TABLE1 
WHERE TABLE1.SESSION = 92
union all
SELECT '',TABLE2.NAME,'' FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.SESSION = 92 AND TABLE2.DATE > '[somedateGoesHere]'
union all
  SELECT '','', TABLE3.NAME FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.SESSION = 92
```